# Rails how to know what page the user came from? Use conditionals to display content based on what page a user navigated from?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to implement a second language (French) into my app. The standard rails internationalization approach seemed like too much for a little 10 page web app that only needs to support 1 additional language. So instead, I am thinking about just creating a second .html.erb for each of my views in the alternative language, and then setting up links within each language to link to the view pages in that language.

The problem comes in the few html.erbs, like `application.html.erb` and the views automatically generated by the Devise user system, where making a second version is probably more trouble than it is worth. On these, I am thinking the easiest route might be to add some conditionals that will show english or french depending on what page the user navigated from or is currently on (since `application.html.erb` displays at the top and bottom of every page).

How can I make a conditional that displays french for application.html.erb and for other views based on what page the user is currently on or what page the user navigated from?

For example I have `my_app.com/index` and `my_app.com/index_fr`. I already have `index_fr` with all the french language, but now I need to also display French in the sections that are published from `application.html.erb`, and there are a few pages like my `my_app.com/users/sign_up` that I don't want to make second views for because I don't want to tinker with Devise too much, where I want to be able to display my English or French language copy based on whether they navigated from, for example, `/index` vs `/index_fr`, `/entries/5` vs `/entries/fr/5` (show pages in english and french), etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please narrow the question title and body to a single question/concept. Please format using code blocks (surrounded by backticks for inline). The only thing that could come to mind, without knowing devise, would be to set hidden attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I am primarily asking about how to know which pages users came from, although I wanted to explain the context in case anyone had a better idea on how to solve my problem.

Comment: http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/03/17/how-rails-sessions-work/ I'd think that storing the preferred language in either the session or a cookie would be the best route.

Answer (score 0):

The `application.html.erb` is a [layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) view, you can make another layout for French and select the layout in the `ApplicationController` at runtime with:

```
class ApplicationController
  layout :layout_by_language

  private

    def layout_by_language
      current_lang == 'french' ? 'application_fr' : 'application_es'
    end

end
```